# Java Android upload image to sever

Tags: java, android

I have a probleme with sending a photo to server. When I want to upload a photo a see in console:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

I did this :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btpic, btnup;
    private Uri fileUri;
    String picturePath;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap photo;
    String ba1;
    public static String URL = "Paste your URL here";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpic);
        btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickpic();
            }
        });

        btnup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        btnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                upload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void upload() {
        // Image location URL
        Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

        // Image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(ba);

//        Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

        // Upload image to server
        new uploadToServer().execute();

    }

    private void clickpic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Cursor to get image uri to display

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imageprev);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

A log :

```
 08:52:35.199 941-941/com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76, PID: 941
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76.MainActivity.clickpic(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                                      at com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                      at com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
11-15 08:52:56.003 941-1089/com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76/lib
11-15 08:54:47.258 941-950/com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.657ms
```

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76">
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your logcat

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath) may be not returning Bitmap looks like its null. Check the picturePath whether image exists in that path or not?

Comment: check if have you given permission to read from sd card in the manifest file

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> and try

Comment: @Raghavendra how I can check this ?

Comment: @Raghavendra I added what you say and I have this 
Process: com.example.krzysiek.myapplication76, PID: 8823
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check if the bitmap bm==null before use and display a toast saying so. Do not vontinue with the vode but return then.

Comment: `have a probleme with sending a photo to server`. No. You have a problem converting a jpg file to a bitmap. The rest of your code is irrelevant.

Comment: decodeFile() will return null if the bitmap would become too big for available memory. Test with a much smaller picture.

Comment: @greenapps so how I can convert a jgp ffile to a bitmap

Comment: I am waiting for the result of the test.

Comment: If you only want to upload that jpg file then it is a pretty bad idea to convert it to a big bitmap in memory first. And then compressing to a different jpg again. For what all this fuss?

Comment: @greenapps I want want to send this picture binary to server. When change a size ipcture it work

Comment: `I want want to send this picture binary to server`. Good idea. Then why are you converting to a base64 string?

Comment: `I want want to send this picture binary to server`. Why dont you just want to send that jpg file to the server? As is.

Comment: @greenapps because They wanto to have this on server . I don't create a server

Comment: `They wanto to have this on server` ?? What is `this`? Binary(as is) or base64? Please be clear.

Comment: @greenapps binary

Comment: So you ssid that you are NOT going to base64 encode data? Strange as you also yold before that the server wants data base64 encoded. And you are doing that in your code too. But ok. Then just upload the bytes of the jpg file unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath); returns null bitmap.
```

The reason would be need read external storage permission. Make sure you have supporting runtime permissions if you are using Android Operating System version which is above 5.0

Also make sure your picturePath represents a file which has URI scheme image.

Good luck there.

Emre